# For Loop function

Tags: vba, excel

I just need help in looping through a column. Each cell should be transferred to a different column but repeated 3x with an interval of 3 empty cells then the next cell from the source column and so on.

Output should look like this:

[image: Output]

I believe that a For Loop can be used to do this but I'm having a hard time with the coding. Any one can help?

```
Dim row As Long

For row = 1 To 3

    Cells(row + 1, 3).Value = [A2]

Next row
```

I'm having a hard time adding an interval of 3 empty cells on it and moving to the next cell on the source column.

Comment: @Macro provide the code you have tried.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer solved if you have gotten the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic looping, I hope this will get you started so you can try to do more of this kind of codeing yourself..

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

 lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 1 To lastrow
     Cells(i + j, 3).Resize(3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
     j = j + 5
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you could achieve this without VBA

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,6)<3,INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-1)/6)+1),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit different code, I hope this help.

```
Dim LastRow, i As Long

LastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Cells(6 * (i - 2) + 2, 3).Resize(3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
Next
```